# How to import HBaseTestingUtility into hbase 0.98.4

Tags: hbase, mockito, powermock

I try to write junit test for Hbase DAO. So i need HBaseTestingUtility or mock for HTableInterface for Hbase version 0.98.4.

Can any help me for find mock for HTableInterface without self creation.